# Bad decrypt on NodeJS Triple DES implementation?

Tags: node.js, encryption

```
var cardInfo = "<Card><CVV></CVV><CardNumber></CardNumber><ExpMonth></ExpMonth><ExpYear></ExpYear><Member></Member></Card>"

function genKeyPair(passphrase){
    var iv = crypto.createHash('md5').update(passphrase).digest('hex').substring(0, 8)
    var key = crypto.createHash('md5').update(passphrase).digest('hex').substring(0, 24)
    return {
        key: key,
        iv: iv
    }
}

function encrypt3DES(key, vector, data){
    var encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv('des3', key, vector)
    var raw = new Buffer(data)
    encryptor.update(raw)
    var encrypted = encryptor.final()
    return encrypted
}

function decrypt3DES(key, vector, data){
    var decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv('des3', key, vector)
    decryptor.update(data)
    var decrypted = decryptor.final()
    return decrypted
}

var key = genKeyPair('test')
var data3DES = encrypt3DES(key.key, key.iv, cardInfo)
var decryptedCard = decrypt3DES(key.key, key.iv, data3DES)
```

So, I get a "bad decrypt" on decryptor.final() and can't figure out why.

1. Node expects a buffer when encrypting so you see I provide that in the beginning of the `encrypt3DES`
2. I put the raw buffer output from encryption straight into the decrypt method

What am I doing wrong here?

*DISCLAIMER* 
No, this is not going to be used in production. I'm just toying around so please hold with the "you don't know what you're doing so you shouldn't do it" talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of `update` are thrown away in your code:

> Returns the enciphered contents, and can be called many times with new data as it is streamed.

The code also uses 3DES ABC keys that do not contain enough entropy (keys should be binary data, not hexadecimals). At least try to use `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)` or try and find an implementation of PBKDF2 in JavaScript.

Comment: I get the same results when using streams and I *believe* this is the correct implementation because ciphers in node are also streams and as such are not meant to be assigned to a new variable when using update.

Comment: I've thoroughly read through the docs of CryptoJS, and I *believe* that you are wrong. Have you **tried** my solution before you gave that comment? I think you should use a `write` or `read` method instead if you want to use them as streams. I don't think they are *sinks* or *sources* either.

Comment: Yes, the first time around I actually used the native streams API (listen for data and end, fire stream.end with input data). I'm going to give it a few more shots and if you're right I'll be sure to return and mark correct :-)

Comment: realized the code would be too big and deleted it; instead I edited the OP

Comment: This returns the `wrong final block` error

`function encrypt3DES(key, vector, data){
        var encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv('des3', key, vector)
        var raw = new Buffer(data)
        var encrypted = encryptor.update(raw)
        encrypted += encryptor.final()
        return encrypted
    }

    function decrypt3DES(key, vector, data){
        var decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv('des3', key, vector)
        var decrypted = decryptor.update(data)
        decrypted += decryptor.final()
        return decrypted
    }`

Answer (score 0):

here is algorithm related key and iv lengths relations, as

```
DES-ECB       Key: 8;  IV: 0
DES-CBC       Key: 8;  IV: 8
DES-CFB       Key: 8;  IV: 8
DES-CFB1      Key: 8;  IV: 8
DES-CFB8      Key: 8;  IV: 8
DES-EDE-CBC   Key: 16; IV: 8
DES-EDE-CFB   Key: 16; IV: 8
DES-EDE-OFB   Key: 16; IV: 8
DES-EDE3-CBC  Key: 24; IV: 8
DESX-CBC      Key: 24; IV: 8
```

and, this is a runnable example

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const iv = '12345678';
const key = '123456'.padEnd(24,'0');
const ivHex = Buffer.from(iv, 'utf8');
const keyHex = Buffer.from(key, 'utf8');


const decrypt = (text)=>{
    const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('DES-EDE3-CBC', keyHex,ivHex);
    let c = cipher.update(text, 'base64','utf8')
    c += cipher.final('utf8');
    return c;
}

const encrypt = (text)=>{
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('DES-EDE3-CBC', keyHex,ivHex);
    let c = cipher.update(text, 'utf8' ,'base64');
    c+=cipher.final('base64');
    return c;
}

const text = '7LBIMxZKDB0=';
const plaintext = decrypt(text);
console.log(plaintext);//123456

const cipherText = encrypt(plaintext);
console.log(cipherText, text === cipherText);//7LBIMxZKDB0= true
```

hope it helps.